# alternativa formulario subformularios access

Tags: ms-access

Estoy haciendo una base de datos con formularios y subformularios. Es la única forma que conozco de enlazar formularios por varios campos (en mi caso, campos cliente, referencia y nº de pedido).

El problema es que en la vista diseño del formulario maestro al tener tantos subformularios asociados (tengo unos 30), tengo que ir moviéndolos de un lado a otro al hacer modificaciones y llega un punto que es muy incómodo porque tengo la pantalla plagada de subformularios.

Por otra parte, tengo que añadir botones internos dentro de cada subformulario para poder cerrarlos.

No sé si es posible alguna alternativa para organizarlo de una manera más práctica y poder ocultar los subformularios en la vista diseño para poder trabajar mejor con el formulario maestro. También me gustaría poder mover los subformularios libremente en vista formulario una vez los abra (mantenimiento los campos asociados) para que se puedan ver los datos del formulario maestro que hay en segundo plano y poder cerrarlos sin tener que crear el botón en cada subformulario.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes meter cada uno de tus subformularios en una pestaña diferente en un control de ficha. Se utiliza para hacer formularios con pestañas.

No tienes que estar moviéndolos. Pruébalo, es justo lo que necesitas.

> **[Crear un formulario con pestañas](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/crear-un-formulario-con-pesta%C3%B1as-6869dee9-3ab7-4f3d-8e65-3a84183c9815)**

Comment: Pues muchas gracias, Elier, muy útil.